# Highcharts - Piecharts - title generated with useHTML overlaps with tooltip generated using useHTML

Tags: highcharts, pie-chart

When I hover on series, It shows perfect data but title in background is also visible.

See these images

1. Actual chart
   [image]
2. Tooltip
   [image]

Here is code link - https://jsfiddle.net/gkd/97mk583y/

tooltip & Title both are generated using `useHTML: true`
How can we make sure title doesn't appear in background of tooltip ?

- opacity in background color is already 1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because both of this elements are outstanding HTML elements try to use this config rather than inline styling:

```
  "tooltip": {
    padding: 0,
    "style": {
      "color": "#FFFFFF"
    },
    "enabled": true,
    "useHTML": true
  },
```

And CSS:

```
.highcharts-tooltip>span {
  padding: 10px;
  margin: 0;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 1);
  z-index: 9999 !important;
}
```

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/z5Lb1hmt/